# I want to change string date time to django date time

Tags: python, django, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Hello everyone I am new to Django and using newsapi to get some news, the API returns a JSON object having a datetime attribute like this `2018-04-22T11:38:05Z`. I want to serialize it into Django `DateTimeField`. I have tried `.date()` but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the string to Python `datetime` object.

```
import datetime

datetime_string = '2018-04-22T11:38:05Z'
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(datetime_obj)
```

**Output**

```
2018-04-22 11:38:05
```